# Running otest results in found old-ABI metadata in image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, terminal

I am trying to run unit test from terminal but it is failing each time. The following message is what I get when I try to run otest in terminal.

```
objc[42339]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set
objc[42339]: found old-ABI metadata in image /Developer/Tools/otest !
Segmentation fault
```

I need the output of the unit test for Hudson integration and I have the iOS deployment target set to 4.2. Here is what I am attempting to run.

```
export SDKROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
export BUILD_DIR=~/Documents/XCode/MyApp/build
export BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR=~/Documents/XCode/MyApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator

export DYLD_ROOT_PATH=$SDKROOT
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=$BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR:$SDKROOT
export IPHONE_SIMULATOR_ROOT=$SDKROOT
export CFFIXED_USER_HOME="~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/"
export OBJC_DISABLE_GC=YES
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR:$SDKROOT
export DYLD_NEW_LOCAL_SHARED_REGIONS=YES
export DYLD_NO_FIX_PREBINDING=YES

arch -i386 /Developer/Tools/otest MyApp.octest
```

Comment: You need an iOS build of otest.  Specifically one targeted to the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bbum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25646/bbum) is correct I was using the **wrong** `otest`. [Described here](http://www.grokkingcocoa.com/how_to_debug_iphone_unit_te.html) I needed to run the following

```
$ find /Developer -name otest
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest
/Developer/Tools/otest
```

Obviously by the output I chose the correct otest for my application and it worked perfectly.